# Angular redirect url in production

Tags: angular

I have a problem when I make my application available in a production environment.
Routes do not work generating 404 error
What do I need to change in my project to be able to work the routes in this environment?

My local: http://localhost:4200/test

Production: http://my-app/test

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { TestComponent } from './tests/test.component';
import { SideNavComponent } from './side-nav/side-nav.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'test', component: TestComponent },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Http:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <base href="/" />
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=0, minimal-ui"
    />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />

    <!-- Favicon icon -->
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
  </head>
  <body class="mat-typography">
    <app-root></app-root>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you must use `HashLocationStrategy` for routing. check this  :
https://angular.io/api/common/HashLocationStrategy

Answer (score 0):

There is configuring options for route present as boolean flag. Option name is `useHash`. By default it is false you need to make it true to load your routes with hash. Changes tobe made in `app-routing.module.ts`

```
RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules, useHash:true })
```

Now if you still want your routes without hash then you need to modify your server settings. Below are settings to be done at apache2. Follow below link.

https://ngmilk.rocks/2015/03/09/angularjs-html5-mode-or-pretty-urls-on-apache-using-htaccess/

Comment: Don´t work. Error 404 page note found: http://my-app/test